# How to extract nodes from first JSON to second one with Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm struggling the second day with this and can't go any further. My JSON is:

```
{
    "test": [
        {
            "features": [
                "none"
            ],
            "AAA": [
                {
                    "BBB": {
                        "CCC": 95,
                        "DDD": 60
                    },
                    "EEE": "123",
                    "FFF": "image/png",
                    "GGG": "222",
                    "HHH": "image"
                },
                {
                    "BBB": {
                        "CCC": 95,
                        "DDD": 60
                    },
                    "EEE": "126",
                    "FFF": "image/jpg",
                    "GGG": "645",
                    "HHH": "image"
                }
            ],
            "III": [],
            "JJJ": {
                "KKK": true
            },
            "LLL": "0",
            "MMM": false,
            "name": "AXA"
        },
        {
            "features": [
                "none"
            ],
            "AAA": [
                {
                    "BBB": {
                        "CCC": 95,
                        "DDD": 60
                    },
                    "EEE": "123",
                    "FFF": "image/png",
                    "GGG": "222",
                    "HHH": "image"
                },
                {
                    "BBB": {
                        "CCC": 95,
                        "DDD": 60
                    },
                    "EEE": "126",
                    "FFF": "image/jpg",
                    "GGG": "645",
                    "HHH": "image"
                }
            ],
            "III": [],
            "JJJ": {
                "SSS": {
                    "Tech": "ABC",
                    "Tech2": "DEF",
                    "Tech3": "GHI"
                },
                "TTT": {
                    "Tech": "ABC",
                    "Tech2": "DEF",
                    "Tech3": "GHI"
                },
                "UUU": {
                    "Tech": "ABC",
                    "Tech2": "DEF",
                    "Tech3": "GHI"
                },
                "WWW": {
                    "Tech": "ABC",
                    "Tech2": "DEF",
                    "Tech3": "GHI"
                    "Tech4": "JKL"
                },
                "KKK": true
            },
            "PERM": {
                "RRR": false
            },
            "X1": "adsada",
            "X2": false,
            "name": "AXA 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract full nodes to a few JSON files.

From my JSON I want to extract the nodes between lines 3 and 36 and from 37 to 94.

The thing is - It won't be always the same, I mean I cannot hard code it to cut the thing in half ;).

I know it's simple with XMLs, but I have still no clue how to do that with JSON. Could anyone help me here a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse out the JSON with the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), which gives you a Python data structure.

Then loop over the `'test'` key and dump each dictionary in that list to a new JSON file:

```
import json

with open(inputjsonfile, 'r') as ifh:
    data = json.load(ifh)

    for i, entry in enumerate(data['test']):
        with open('outputfile-test-{}.json'.format(i), 'w') as ofh:
            json.dump(entry, ofh)
```

You can further filter the entries as needed, or use data from the entries to generate a filename; `entry['name']` is the name value of each entry, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What do to with json ? Well, the same thing as with XML : parse it.

=> http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I have to problem iterating through the file printing everything out, but I need to limit to one node. i.e. from the sample json extract full node where name = "AXA 2" to second json file.

Comment: Have you read the doc for the standard lib's json module (link in my answer above) ?

Comment: Yes, I did, but let's be honest, the JSON chapter of the manual is not the best one written there.

Comment: @jakkolwiek: oh yeah, well... It starts with practical examples and goes on with the api documentation. Yeah sure, this and a Python shell is certainly not enough to get started. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could decode your json and use it as a python element (`list` and `dict`)

```py
import json
data = json.loads(my_json)
print data['test'][0] # This would be your element between the lines 3 and 36
print data['test'][1] # This would be from 37 to 94
```

If you want to convert it to `str` again:

```
print json.dumps(data['test'][0])
print json.dumps(data['test'][1])
```

Comment: There is a top-level dictionary, so it'll be `data['test'][0]`.